# Prolog summing first indices of lists

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm new to Prolog, trying to sum up only the first elements of each list.

```
takeFirst([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],R).   --> R=1+4+7=12
```

It keeps outputting false and I don't understand what I'm missing here.

```
takeFirst([HF|_],[],HF):-!. 
takeFirst([H|L1],R):- H=[_|_], L1=[_|_],!,takeFirst(H,L1,NN), R is NN.
takeFirst([HF|_],[K|L2],HF):- takeFirst(K,L2,NN), HF is HF+NN.
```

does anyone see what is wrong here?

Comment: What should be done in case there is an empty list in the given list?

Comment: you cannot *add* elements in Prolog; Prolog is a *declarative* language, meaning that variables cannot change when they are assigned.

Comment: I mistakenly said "adding them", but I menat returning a list of first element of every list. in this case returning '[1,4,7]' as i said. Im basically asking if i could replace 'Rb is Ra+HH' to 'Rb=[Ra,HH]' , because i had some trouble with that earlier

Comment: A simple approach would be: `sum_first(L, Sum) :- maplist(head, L, Heads), sumlist(Heads, Sum).` and define `head([H|_], H).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your code is rather chaotic: you define a `takeFirst/3` first (that probably should be the base case?). Next you define two recursive cases, but you somehow pass the *head* the list in the recursive call, etc.

Actually the problem is easy to solve. You first better redirect your `takeFirst/2` to a takeFirst/3` with an *accumulator*:

```
takeFirst(L,R) :-
    takeFirst(L,0,R).
```

Next we consider a base case: we reached the end of the list:

```
takeFirst([],R,R).
```

In this case we reached the end, and so the value of the accumulator, the variable we pass that keeps track of the sum thus far, is returned as the result.

In the recursive case, we are given a list `[H|T]` and we are interested in the *head of the head* `HH` so `[[HH|_]|T]`. In that case we add `HH` to the accumulator and do a recursive call with `T`:

```
takeFirst([[HH|_]|T],Ra,R) :-
    Rb is Ra+HH,
    takeFirst(T,Rb,R).
```

So putting it together we get:

```
takeFirst(L,R) :-
    takeFirst(L,0,R).

takeFirst([],R,R).
takeFirst([[HH|_]|T],Ra,R) :-
    Rb is Ra+HH,
    takeFirst(T,Rb,R).
```

Something that was not very clear in your question is what should be done if there is an empty list in your list, like `[[1,2,3],[],[7,8,9]]`. The above predicate will fail: it expects that all lists have at least one element. In case you simply want to ignore these lists, you can alter your code into:

```
takeFirst2(L,R) :-
    takeFirst2(L,0,R).

takeFirst2([],R,R).
takeFirst2([[]|T],Ra,R) :-
    takeFirst2(T,Ra,R).
takeFirst2([[HH|_]|T],Ra,R) :-
    Rb is Ra+HH,
    takeFirst2(T,Rb,R).
```

So we add a case where the list follows the pattern `[[]|T]`, in which case we simply perform a recursive call with the tail `T`.

Based on the given above predicates, constructing a list of heads is not hard as well:

```
heads([],[])
heads([[HH|_]|TA],[HH|TB]) :-
    heads(TA,TB).
```